# C++11: can we create `std::shared_ptr` type `std::atomic` variable

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I am trying to create a `std::shared_ptr` type `std::atomic` variable.
compile on online [compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
//using namespace std;

class abc
{
public:
std::atomic <std::shared_ptr <int>> abl;
std::shared_ptr<int> a;  

void set(int x)
{
    abl.store(std::make_shared<int>(10) , std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

void out()
{
    a = abl.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::cout<< "value" << *a;
}
};

int main()
{
    abc ab;
    ab.set(10);
    ab.out();
    std::cout << "Hello World"; 

    return 0;
}
```

but getting following error

```
error: static assertion failed: std::atomic requires a trivially copyable type                                              
       static_assert(__is_trivially_copyable(_Tp),
```

but when i tried it on my linux machine with complier version gcc 4.8(C++11) it compiled successfully but crashed.

i go through [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-03/msg00030.html) and found shared_ptr is surely not TriviallyCopyable.
compiler should give compile time error

Comment: Prefer `atomic_shared_ptr` from C++17...

Comment: Interestingly, the standard just says *"The type of the template parameter T shall be trivially copyable"*. That's a requirement for the programmer, not for the compiler - so it *can* tell you that to be nice, but isn't required to. Also see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63322